# How can I disable overscan on a secondary display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, overscan

I'm using Ubuntu on a laptop, and everything displays fine on the built-in display. I have a Digital Television connected as a secondary display via HDMI and there's overscan that I can't figure out how to get rid of. The television is a Vizio VA19L HDTV10T.

I've read on here about trying with xrandr, but I'm really new to Linux and I don't know what to adjust to make it fit right. I also read something about xrandr with the "underscan on" arguments but that throws a long error.

Edit: the TV does not have an overscan setting I can configure, that's why I read about xrandr. It does have a "wide" setting, but apparently I can't change that when connected via HDMI (and I don't have any other way to connect).

Comment: Have you tried disabling overscan on the TV?

Comment: I think this should be adjusted on the TV (or external monitor). There should be an option called "1:1 pixel mapping" on the TV ***which should be enabled*** for the current source (input). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1:1_pixel_mapping

Comment: @danzel I forgot to mention in the post that the TV doesn't have an overscan setting. Whoops. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli see my other comment, turns out I can't mention two users in one comment

Comment: You may try "H/V Position and Size" adjustments. See page 35-36 of your TV manual. (I just downloaded it from http://cdn.vizio.com/manuals/kb/legacy/va19lhdtv10tmanual.pdf )

Comment: @FedonKadifeli position just moves the image around and doesn’t change the size of what’s shown. Size is disabled. 

Anything I could try in Ubuntu instead of on the TV?